# I need a react spinning wheel with an arrow at the top, with the ability to control the probabilities

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am working on a React application that utilizes Chart.js to create a pie chart. The pie chart should dynamically update based on the number of segments provided. Initially, I generated the data array dynamically based on the number of segments. However, when I changed the data array to a predefined set of data objects, the chart stopped working properly.

Here is a simplified version of the component:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
import "./style.css";

const SpinWheelApp = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState();
  const wheelRef = useRef(null);
  const spinBtnRef = useRef(null);
  const finalValueRef = useRef(null);
  const [numSegments, setNumSegments] = useState(2); // State to track number of segments

  useEffect(() => {
    function generateRotationValues(num) {
      const fullCircle = 360;
      const degreeSpan = fullCircle / num;
      const rotationValues = [];

      let previousEndDegree = 0; // Initialize the previous end degree

      for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        const startDegree = previousEndDegree + 1; // Start degree of the current segment
        const endDegree = startDegree + degreeSpan - 1; // End degree of the current segment

        const rotationSegment = {
          minDegree: startDegree,
          maxDegree: endDegree,
          value: i + 1,
        };

        rotationValues.push(rotationSegment);

        previousEndDegree = endDegree; // Update the previous end degree for the next iteration
      }

      return rotationValues;
    }

    const rotationValues = generateRotationValues(numSegments);

    console.log({ rotationValues });

    const data = Array.from({ length: numSegments }, () => 16); // Create an array with 'numSegments' number of elements each with a value of 16
    const pieColors = Array.from({ length: numSegments * 2 }, (_, i) =>
      i % 2 === 0 ? "#8b35bc" : "#b163da"
    );

    const wheel = wheelRef.current;
    const spinBtn = spinBtnRef.current;
    const finalValue = finalValueRef.current;

    const spinPointer = {
      id: "spinPointer",
      afterDatasetsDraw(chart, args, plugins) {
        const {
          ctx,
          chartArea: { top },
        } = chart;
        const xCenter = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data[0].x;

        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "gold";
        ctx.moveTo(xCenter, top + 30);
        ctx.lineTo(xCenter - 15, top);
        ctx.lineTo(xCenter + 15, top);
        ctx.fill();
      },
    };

    let myChart = new Chart(wheel, {
      plugins: [ChartDataLabels, spinPointer],
      type: "pie",
      data: {
        labels: Array.from({ length: numSegments }, (_, i) => i + 1), // Generate labels dynamically
        datasets: [{ backgroundColor: pieColors, data: data }],
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        animation: { duration: 1 },
        plugins: {
          tooltip: false,
          legend: { display: false },
          datalabels: {
            color: "#ffffff",
            formatter: (_, context) =>
              context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex],
            font: { size: 24 },
          },
        },
      },
    });

    function rotation() {
      // Calculate the total degrees for two complete rotations
      const totalDegrees = 360 * 6;

      // Set a random final rotation angle that is at least two complete rotations
      const finalRotation = 360 * 10 + Math.random() * 10000; // Allows for 10 complete rotations and adds some randomness

      // Define the initial rotation
      let currentRotation = myChart.config.data.datasets[0].rotation || 0;

      // Define the initial increment for each frame
      let increment = 50;

      // Define the deceleration rate
      const deceleration = 0.98;

      // Define a function to animate the spinning
      function animateSpin() {
        // Increase the rotation angle by the increment
        currentRotation += increment;

        // Update the chart with the new rotation angle
        myChart.config.data.datasets[0].rotation = currentRotation;
        myChart.update();

        // Gradually reduce the increment to simulate deceleration
        increment *= deceleration;

        // Check if the final rotation angle is reached or increment becomes very small
        if (currentRotation < finalRotation && increment > 0.1) {
          // Continue animating
          requestAnimationFrame(animateSpin);
        } else {
          // Stop spinning and determine the selected segment
          determineSelectedSegment();
        }
      }

      // Start the spinning animation
      animateSpin();
    }

    function determineSelectedSegment() {
      const angle = 180 / Math.PI;
      let selectedIndex = -1;

      myChart.getDatasetMeta(0).data.forEach((datapoint, index) => {
        const netStartAngle = (datapoint.startAngle * angle) % 360;
        const netEndAngle = (datapoint.endAngle * angle) % 360;

        // Assuming 270 degrees is the indicator's position
        if (270 > netStartAngle && 270 < netEndAngle) {
          selectedIndex = index + 1; // Output the selected segment index
        }
      });

      setResult(selectedIndex);

      console.log("Selected Segment:", selectedIndex);
    }

    spinBtn.addEventListener("click", rotation);

    return () => {
      spinBtn.removeEventListener("click", rotation);
      myChart.destroy();
    };
  }, [numSegments]);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const value = parseInt(event.target.value, 10); // Parse the input value as an integer
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      setNumSegments(value); // Update the number of segments
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="container">
        <canvas ref={wheelRef} id="wheel"></canvas>
        <button ref={spinBtnRef} id="spin-btn">
          Spin
        </button>
        <input
          type="number"
          value={numSegments}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          min="1"
        />
      </div>
      <div id="final-value">
        {result ? result : <p>Click On The Spin Button To Start</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SpinWheelApp;
```

The issue arises when using a predefined set of data objects (chartData). The chart does not update properly when the number of segments changes. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It would be useful if you put this code in a stackblitz or codesandbox which could be forked and debugged.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/medo2203/Spinning-Wheel/main?import=true

this is the sandbox code